# Custom Adapter with check box values is not rechecked when reopen the activity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with custom list view with adapter. In which i am selecting many names by checking the check box. when press the OK button,I am getting the selected values back to the previous activity. When reopen the activity,The already selected values in check box is not rechecked again. How to solve this issue?. 
Code

```
public class MultiselectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final Context mContext;
private final List<TeamModel> items = null;
private final int mResource;
SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
public String[] teamIDValues;

ArrayList<Object> ListObject;

public MultiselectAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
                          @NonNull ArrayList objects ){
    super(context, resource, 0, objects);

    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mResource = resource;
    ListObject = objects;

    mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(ListObject.size());
    System.out.println("teh size vaooo --"+mCheckStates.size());
    System.out.println("teh objects vaooo --"+objects.size());
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

    mCheckStates.put((Integer) compoundButton.getTag(), isChecked);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView name;
    protected TextView id;
    protected CheckBox check;

}

@Override
public @NonNull View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new  ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResource, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idval);
        holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choseboxes);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.name, holder.name);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.idval, holder.id);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.choseboxes, holder.check);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.check.setTag(position);


    holder.check.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    if(ListObject.get(position) instanceof TeamModel.Data)
    {
     //   System.out.println("teh valus are--"+((TeamModel.Data) ListObject.get(position)).getDescription());
        holder.name.setText(((TeamModel.Data) ListObject.get(position)).getDescription());
        holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(((TeamModel.Data) ListObject.get(position)).getId()));

    }
    else if(ListObject.get(position) instanceof TeamModel.GroupData)
    {
      //  System.out.println("teh valus are-geroup name--"+((TeamModel.GroupData) ListObject.get(position)).getCceTeamName());
        holder.name.setText(((TeamModel.GroupData) ListObject.get(position)).getCceTeamName());
        holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(((TeamModel.GroupData) ListObject.get(position)).getId()));
    }
    // holder.check.setChecked(items.get(position).isSelected());
    return convertView;
}
public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
}

public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

}

public void toggle(int position) {
    setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

}
}
```

---

Comment: you must save instances. Try this example: https://gist.github.com/curioustechizen/6ed0981b013f63236f0b

Comment: First you have to call select activity by calling `startActivityForResult()` then After pressing ok button pass to all selected value to previous activity in `setResult()`. Next time pass data in to intent to start select activity.

Comment: you need to manage save instances or store your states so that whether in onCreate() or onResume() you can recall them!
Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal Ok. How to pass the selected values inside the list. Now i already getting the list which is populating in list view. How to pass the selected values inside the overall loading list and make the some values rechecked?.Please look at my code

Comment: Create a filed in Team class as select and set the value of check box.

Comment: Please add the activity with checkboxs code

Comment: @MarcGV    Intent intent = new Intent(PreScheduleActivity.this,TeamSelectActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);     i can pass the selected values here. But i dont know how to pass the selected values inside the loading list to recheck it in adapter. Please help me

Comment: @MarcGV    adapter = new MultiselectAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.multiselect_row,object);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);    This is how i everytime pass the full list of values to load in adapter. The adapter code is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the checked names in `SharedPreferences` (for example) and check in your activity's `onCreate()` the preferences to set previous values.

The activity is created from 0 when you reopen it.

---

**UPDATE:**

To pass the checked values:

```
long[] checkedPositions = new long[]{1, 2, 6, 9, 12}; //Example checked positions

Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("checked_names", checkedPositions);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

To check the checkboxes you could use your adapter's method after the adapter is created in the new activity:

```
public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

}
```

Or you can create a new constructor for example.